# How can I Dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I was wondering how can I dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 without any problems or errors. I am on windows 8 build 8400.

Comment: I have never used Windows 8 (and never intend to), but one thing I do know: install Windows 8 *first*, and Ubuntu after that.  If you install Ubuntu first, then the Windows boot manager will overwrite GRUB and prevent you from booting into Linux without reinstalling GRUB (and I am pretty sure that this is not an accident).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system)

Answer (score 2):

I have a windows 8/ 12.04 dual boot.

Due to a lack of drivers on the boot disk I needed to install 11.10 then upgrade. I followed these instructions: http://www.intowindows.com/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu/. I would guess they would work directly for 12.04 but I can't verify. After upgrading to 12.04 UEFI boot would load windows, legacy boot off of hard drive booted Ubuntu. Boot repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) fixed this, now UEFI boot gives grub with Ubuntu and windows options. You need to be running the 64-bit version for this last part, boot repair says 32-bit doesn't support UEFI boot.

Answer (score -1):

i have ubuntu 12.04 64 bit install first and i want to install window 8

so first thing we need to do is divide our hardrive for window 8 using Gparted linux program CD and make Ubuntu live usb .

second divide hardrive **NTFS** file for window 8 using Gparted program CD and to use Gparted program CD must change boot pirority in Bio setting first and choose function boot from CD, otherwise you can not divide hardisk while you are running ubuntu.

thirst install window 8 CD in the part of hardrive where you have already divide.

and reboot computer so you will not see ubuntu anymore but dont worry

four reboot your computer using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits live USB and run Ubuntu from USB ,and choose try Ubuntu function

five open ubuntu sofware center and download boot repair program and choose recommende function

reboot again and you are done