# How can I easliy boot Ubuntu and Windows 8?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I Dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201154/how-can-i-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-8)

I've had various problems with Ubuntu and Windows 8 on dual-boot, how can I solve this in an easy manner without messing my partitions or my boot loader?

Comment: Are you asking anything? or just providing a solution?

Comment: It's just a solution I've find!

Comment: Please make your question a *question* and post your solution as the answer, this is how the site works. I have edited this for you now **Please** add your Answer because as simple as it is, it's the most *efficient* one.

Comment: OK Uri, I've done!

Comment: @Giorgio Please move your answer to the Duplicate question, and  just be as direct as possible, that means no "story of your problem", good formatting, and just the answer itself.

Comment: what does it means " move your answer to the Duplicate question" ? what I should do?

Comment: @Giorgio Put your answer in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my experience could help other people in mine same situation:

I've had a lot of problem with dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8 in two partition in a same HD:
Every time automatically started  Windows and never ubuntu....
I've try all guides for disable Secure boot,etc... but without solution.

I've solved all dual boot problems, installing Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 in two separated HD.

My situation is

HD n°1:

- 1st partition with Ubuntu 12.04
- 2nd partition for backup, ntfs formatted

HD n°2

- Windows 8. from windows, i can read/write on ntfs partition into 1st HD

When switch on my computer, into GRUB page,I can choose between Ubuntu and Winfdows 8, but only Ubuntu can be booted; If i choose Windows 8 is shown a message which says : "error impossible find EFI... etc... or something like that".
If i boot directly windows 8 from boot menu, it work!

Maybe I've understand what is the problem:

Windows 8, it's installed in a traditional mode, NOT UEFI, and I can see this from tool partition manager: in my Windows 8 HD isn't available EFI partiion, or well, the boot partion isn't EFI, but traditional I suppose (i've upgrade it from windows 7).

When I've install Ubuntu 12.04, I've choose EFI boot mode for the installation. (with Gparted I can see EFI boot partion on my HD).

My Mother board support both system BIOS and EFI, but i think GRUB system work only if both, Windows / Ubuntu, use the same boot mode: UEFI or BIOS.
**If one is UEFI and other BIOS not work.**

At the moment, for me is a good solution use 2 HD:
When i boot PC, start automatically Ubuntu, and if i want use Windows8, from boot menu (F12  for me) I choose HD which has windows 8.

All works properly!
Ok is not a practise solution, but works...